# If my displacement is Euler's number $e$

Tags: kinematics, mathematics, calculus

So, differential of $e^x$ ($e$=Euler's No.) is equal to $e^x$.

Now imagine I put $x=1$ and travel with a displacement $e$ (which is a constant) so we will be not moving anywhere since our displacement is constant. But (and this is where the question starts) as the differential of displacement w.r.t. time will be velocity and it will be $e^x$ where we put $x=1$ so velocity=$e$.

So now we have a constant non zero velocity but we also have constant displacement, that means even if we have a velocity we are not moving anywhere with passage of time.

I know I am wrong somewhere please can you tell me where. And please don't mind if it's a silly mistake.

Comment: The notion of "constant displacement" does not make sense.  Displacement is change in position and the change happens during some time.  The position can be said to be fixed (no time dependence). You can have constant rate of displacement which means constant velocity.

Comment: \begin{aligned}y\left( t\right) =e^{x\left( t\right) }\\
v=\dfrac{dy}{dt}=e^{x\left( t\right) } \dfrac{dx}{dt}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The velocity function $v(t)$ is the derivative of the displacement function $x(t)$, so $v(t)= x'(t)$.  If $x(t)=e$ (a constant), then $v(t) = x'(t) = 0$.

If $x(t) = e^t$ (in some units), then $x'(t)= e^t$ as well, but in that case, $x(t)$ is not constant.